# Is it better to keep a laptop or smartphone battery always at 100% or to let it discharging before recharging?

Tags: mac, laptop, android, iphone

Is it better to keep a laptop or smartphone battery always at 100% or to let it discharging before recharging ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1590789/401839

Comment: and for smartphones ?

Comment: doesn't matter.  Both smart phones and laptops are basically portable computers, so the expected behaviors would be the same.  What matters more is what type of battery is being used.

Comment: From my experience the best way to destroy a Lio battery is to charge it very frequently between 90% and 100%. If you keep a smartphone connected to the charger or a PC they usually do exact this, e.g. stop charging and start charging if the battery drops below 95%. Lio batteries are best kept between 30% and 80% then they will last the longest.

Comment: How do you recharge a battery at 100%? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Smartphones are off topic here at any rate.

Comment: It's better to not let it worry you at all. If they don't die through excess recharge cycle count, they will simply die of ageing. The difference is truly marginal. [A recharge cycle is not  'let it go flat, charge it up', it is far more complex than that.]